# Will a Mongoose queries `then` call occur after any passed in callback completes?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, es6-promise

I realize that the standard practice for promises in Mongoose is to use exec(), but the following works (or at least appears to) and I want to understand the flow.  I'm not against using `exec`, I'm just exploring this a bit to learn.

In the following Mongoose operation:

```
let id:string;

SomeDocument.remove({}, (err) => { //clears collection
  someDoc = new SomeDocument(data); //creates a new doc for the collection. Id is created here from what I understand.
  someDoc.save( (err, result) => { doSomething(); });//doSomething gets called sometime in the future.
  id = someDoc._id.toString();
}).then( (result) => {doSomethingElse(id)});//This works - but will doSomethingElse always be called after the first annonymous callback completes?
```

I get that `doSomething()` will just get called at some future point - no problem.  The question is, will the first callback to the remove call complete prior to `doSomethingElse` in the `then` call being called.  It seems to be, in that the `id` is correctly populated in `doSomethingElse`, but I want to make sure that isn't just a fluke of timing - i.e. I want to know if I can rely on that callback completing prior to the `then`.  I'm using standard ES6 promises (NodeJS.Global.Promise).

The alternative is that maybe `then` is called after the remove operation completes, but prior to the callback completing (doesn't seem to - but I want to confirm).

Set me straight if I'm explaining this incorrectly.

Comment: well, its a callback to save, so it will be called after the save operation completes which may actually complete after the `id = someDoc._id.toString()` line is executed.

Comment: Sorry - that was just an error in the post.  doSomethingElse is being called from within an anon function.  

I can tell you that when I actually execute this the id is correctly populated for doSomething else so the line `id = someDoc._id.toString()` is being called prior to `doSomethingElse(id)`.  So at the least it potentially gets executed after the remove callback - the question is if this will happen reliably (it does in my case, but it could just be a fluke).

Comment: Haha - yes, you are right.  I should have just posted my actual code but it was kinda messy.  Apparently when trying to 'simplify' it, I screwed it up substantially.  I fixed that.  Thanks!  Still trying to figure out the bottom line though - will a function passed to the `then` always be executed after a function passed as a callback to the operation I'm calling `then` on.  Specifically - which is executed first - the callback or the `then`?

Comment: Reading the code [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L671) it looks like the callback is called after the promise is resolved. However, due to `.then` callback being called asynchronously (as per Promise/A+ specification), the `.then` callback would be guaranteed to run after any *synchronous* code in the `remove` callback - so I think your code is safe

Comment: Thanks!  Just so I fully understand this (I'm still learning) - the reason that it is safe is even though they are both async, but the first async callback in `remove` is added to the event queue prior to the `then`, so even though they are async, the sync portions within will be guaranteed to run in that order just because that is the order in which they were added to the event queue?  I may not be using the correct language in all cases - feel free to school me, but conceptually that makes sense.

Comment: I believe the order would be `anonymous callback`, `doSomethingElse` then  `doSomething`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as @JaromandaX explained in the comments the order of callbacks is deterministic.

However, it's still bad code, and you should not rely on this behaviour. If you are using promises, don't pass a callback to `remove` at all; only pass callbacks to `then`!

```
SomeDocument.remove({})
.then(() => {
  const someDoc = new SomeDocument(data);
  someDoc.save().then(doSomething); // doSomething will get called in the future.
  return someDoc._id.toString();
//^^^^^^
})
.then(doSomethingElse); // doSomethingElse will get passed the id
```

`doSomethingElse` will get called with the result of the previous callback, which is *guaranteed* to have been completed for that.

Comment: Agreed - I'm actually refactoring over to do things that way but for various reasons I have to live with some mixed code for a bit. Also I just wanted to know for sure - now I know that the order of callbacks is deterministic which is useful!